# How to get hostname with largest number in the inventory

Tags: ansible

How to extract a hostname with the largest number and use that hostname in the mount command as shown below? Basically, I have only one volume that needs to be mounted across all hosts in the group and the volume is created with the hostname with the largest number if that makes sense.

```
server1 
server2  
vol_server2 => need to be mounted on server1 and 2.
```

The **`mymount`** variable is set globally

The **`mymontvol`** var is set in the local role vars file

```yaml
mymountvol: storage:/{{ inventory_hostname }}_dbfiles
```

Here is the `mount` task:

```yaml
- name: mount volume
  mount:
    name: "{{ mymount }}"
    state: mounted
    fstype: nfs
    src: "{{ mymountvol }}"
    opts: rw,bg,hard,nointr,nolock,noatime
  when: mymount is defined and mymountvol is defined 
  become: true
  become_user: root
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex to first select matching hosts from all existing hosts then extract the highest number.

- Get all hosts can be done via the [`groups.all`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) special variable
- Selecting the matching hosts can be done with the [`select`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.select) filter and the [`regex`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings) test: `select('regex', '^' ~ server_prefix ~ '\d+$')`
- Getting only the numeric part can be done with [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map) filter along with  the [`regex_replace`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions) one: `map('regex_replace', '^' ~ server_prefix ~ '(\d+)$', '\1')`
- You will need to convert those values of the list, still with a `map`, in [`int`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.int)
- There is a built-in [`max`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.max) filter in Jinja

So, all this together give you the task:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    selected_host: >-
      {{
        server_prefix ~ (
          groups.all
          | select('regex', '^' ~ server_prefix ~ '\d+$')
          | map('regex_replace', '^' ~ server_prefix ~ '(\d+)$', '\1')
          | map('int')
          | max
        )
      }}
  vars:
    server_prefix: server
```

---

Given the inventory:

```yaml
all:
  hosts:
    server1:
    server2:
    server42:
    server101:
```

And those two tasks:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    selected_host: >-
      {{
        server_prefix ~ (
          groups.all
          | select('regex', '^' ~ server_prefix ~ '\d+$')
          | map('regex_replace', '^' ~ server_prefix ~ '(\d+)$', '\1')
          | map('int')
          | max
        )
      }}
  vars:
    server_prefix: server

- debug:
    var: selected_host
```

This yields:

```
TASK [debug] ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  selected_host: server101
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, given the hosts

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
server1
server2
server42
server101
```

[declare the variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence)

```yaml
max: "{{ groups.all|map('split', 'server')|map('last')|map('int')|max }}"
selected_host: "server{{ max }}"
```

give

```yaml
selected_host: server101
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your responses and appreciate it. I came up with something very simple by defining the variables in the role vars file e.g.

role/my_role/vars

```
superhost: "{{ (groups[group_names[0]] | sort)[-1] }}"
dbdir: path:/{{ superhost }}_dbdir
```

The dbdir variable is then used in the task below which works.

```
  - name: mount vol
    mount:
      name: "{{ source_files }}"
      state: mounted
      fstype: nfs
      src: "{{ dbdir }}"
```